# Efficient usage of MPI_Allreduce

Tags: c, mpi

I have on every processor a list `range` with numbers. I want to determine the maximum number of every row of these lists `range`.

[image]

The first four lists `range` for every processor P0-P3. The red list contains the maximum values of each row which every processor after `MPI_Allreduce` gets.

Here is a working version of my code:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <mpi.h>

//#define KEY_MAX 100

typedef struct{
    int myrank;
    int numprocs;
    int *range;
} SubDomainKeyTree;

void compRange(SubDomainKeyTree *s, int myrank, int numprocs){
    s->myrank = myrank;
    s->numprocs = numprocs;

    // Allocate memory for (numprocs+1) ranges
    s->range = malloc((numprocs+1) * sizeof(int));
    // Compute range values
    for(int p=0; p<=numprocs; p++){
        s->range[p] = rand()%100;
    }

    for(int p=0; p<s->numprocs; p++){
        if(s->myrank == p){
        for(int k=0; k<=s->numprocs; k++){
            printf("Processor %d: %d random number is %d\n", p, k, s->range[k]);
        }
        printf("\n");
        }
    }
    }

    void compDynRange(SubD *s){

        int rangeForAll[s->numprocs+1];
        //////////////////////////////////
        // This is not really efficient //
        //////////////////////////////////
        for(int r=0; r<=s->numprocs; r++){
            MPI_Allreduce(&s->range[r], &rangeForAll[r], 1, MPI_INT, MPI_MAX, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
        }

    for(int p=0; p<s->numprocs; p++){
        if(s->myrank == p){
            for(int k=0; k<=s->numprocs; k++){
                s->range[k] = rangeForAll[k];
                printf("Processor %d: %d random number after MPI_Allreduce is %d\n", p, k, s->range[k]);
            }
            printf("\n");
        }
    }
}

int main(int argc, char **argv){

    int nameLen;
    char processorName[MPI_MAX_PROCESSOR_NAME];

    int myrank;           // Rank of processor
    int numprocs;         // Number of processes
    MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &myrank);
    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &numprocs);
    MPI_Get_processor_name(processorName,&nameLen);
    MPI_Status status;

    time_t t;
    srand((unsigned)time(NULL)+myrank*numprocs+nameLen);

    SubD s;
    compRange(&s, myrank, numprocs);

    compDynRange(&s);
    MPI_Finalize();
    return 0;
}
```

I use a for-loop which seems highly inefficient to me. Here I compute the maximum value of every row of all lists one after the other.

But can I use `MPI_Allreduce` without that for-loop?

I already tried that instead of the for-loop which does not work.

`MPI_Allreduce(&s->range, &rangeForAll, s->numprocs+1, MPI_INT, MPI_MAX, MPI_COMM_WORLD);`

Can someone give me a hint how I can do that?

Comment: Did you really use the `&` like in your question? If so, just remove them from the call to `MPI_Allreduce()` and that should just work...

Comment: @Gilles Perfect! That works!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As already hinted in comment, the error you had in you code was that instead of passing the arrays containing your send and receive buffers, you were passing some pointers to them. I imagine that this error was simply coming fro the change from a single element used initially (like `&s->range[r]`) which was perfectly correct, to the full array by just removing the indexed access (ie `&s->range`) which was wrong.

So as explained, using:

```
MPI_Allreduce(s->range, rangeForAll, s->numprocs+1, MPI_INT, MPI_MAX, MPI_COMM_WORLD)
```

just does the trick. However, since you want to get the results into the `s->range` arrays rather than the temporary `rangeFarAll` ones, you'd better off not defining the later at all, and use the `MPI_IN_PLACE` keyword as sending parameter and `s->range` as receiving one. The call becomes:

```
MPI_Allreduce(MPI_IN_PLACE, s->range, s->numprocs+1, MPI_INT, MPI_MAX, MPI_COMM_WORLD)
```

and `s->range` acts both as sending and receiving buffer. Therefore, the final results will all be in the `s->range` buffers after the call, sparing you the need of doing the copy explicitly.